# MySQL LEFT JOIN not returning all rows from the left table

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a blog system recently, and I ran into an issue. I have two tables, one for blog posts, and another for comments on those posts. This is the query that I am currently using for retrieving of all post information and also the number of comments:

```
SELECT bp.*, COUNT(bpc.id) AS post_comments
FROM blog_posts AS bp
LEFT JOIN blog_post_comments AS bpc ON bpc.post_id = bp.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Now, as I stated in the title, this only returns me data about one post, although it should return 10 posts. Why is this so?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the tables with the data. Better..use sqlfiddle.com

Comment: looks like you are missing some basic knowledge, perhaps this would help : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx

Comment: I never actually followed a MySQL tutorial, except at the beginning to get to know the syntax. I learned all myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use COUNT, it will consider all posts as the same.
Try this to see if it works:

```
SELECT bp.*, COUNT(bpc.id) AS post_comments
FROM blog_posts AS bp
LEFT JOIN blog_post_comments AS bpc ON bpc.post_id = bp.id 
GROUP BY bp.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I'm not sure if that's the problem. Just guessing. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `GROUP BY` clause, and since MySQL is lenient about aggregate functions and columns in the `SELECT` not appearing in the group by, it collapses down to one row showing the total count, but mixed column values from other columns.

```
SELECT bp.*, COUNT(bpc.id) AS post_comments
FROM blog_posts AS bp
LEFT JOIN blog_post_comments AS bpc ON bpc.post_id = bp.id
GROUP BY bp.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The more portable way to do this for RDBMS other than MySQL would be to join against a subquery that returns only the `post_id` and the number of posts per id, allowing the rest of the columns from `blog_posts` to be selected without appearing in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  bp.*,
  bcount.counts
FROM 
  blog_posts AS bp
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS counts 
     FROM blog_post_comments 
     GROUP BY post_id
  ) bcounts ON bp.id = bcounts.post_id
```

Comment: @DanyKhalife Because first answers attract votes around here. Thorough ones get relegated down the list, even if they arrive two seconds later. :)

Comment: @Micheal yea it's a shame though, keep it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You get one record because [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)() is an aggregate function. You should add a GROUP BY clause  and [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)() will work as you wanted.

Comment: I did not know that before. Thanks!